# Can i host a rails app via hostgator and FTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, ftp

Can you deploy a ruby on rails application to hostgator via FTP. if you Can, Can you guys please Tel me how i do it :) do you have to put something inside your project or is there another Way to host via hostgator?
Greetings from Ludvig.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Any host provider service will give you FTP to connect to your files for additon/deletion.
I think you are not aware on hosting and host provides.. :P

Answer (score 1):

If you buy hostgator VPS you can deploy rails application. You can not deploy your rails app (like version 4) on the Shared hosting of hostgator.

FTP is not important issue. You can upload your source code via FTP or other way like cloning from git repo. To deploy the rails app your hosting server must install Rails, Ruby and other packages.

Comment: So i am able to host my rails project using FTP?

Comment: You can upload it via ftp. after then you have to configure more on your rails app. from this link you will get an idea how to deploy rails app - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JV636bzlO_s